# Is brethren a currently used term for plural of brother (monks)?

Tags: terminology

General use of brethren as meaning is considering archaic and not used. Is it in current usage in the Christian world?

Comment: Of coarse it is. Brethren applies to priest monks as well non ordained monks.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394).

Comment: 'Brethren' is also used in the titles of several denominations, such as the Plymouth Brethren and Mennonite Brethren. It's accepted that it's an archaic word, and members of the denominations would not normally use it except to refer to members of the denomination.

Comment: There is difference between a title of a group and a plural- someone would have to write or say 2 brethren. Suggested ways to answer this are to quote from a Vatican document or  maybe there is priests or  monasteries association for inter-organisational coordination.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is a question about Christianity as such. The *Oxford English Dictionary* for “brother” has an entire section devoted to the religious sense of the word (section A.III), with examples from the 20th and 21st centuries, including the plural “brethren”.

In addition I noticed these secular uses of the word:

- “His attempts at ‘contributing’ were not welcomed by many of his
  brethren officers.” (Horn & M. Wyczynski in *Warrior Chiefs*; 2001)
- “Scores of exiled Tibetans..set out on foot towards Tibet to support
  their brethren who are facing oppression under the Chinese regime.”
  (*Hindustan Times*; 2008)

Answer (score 1):

**Is brethren a currently used term for plural of brother (monks)?**

Yes, brethren is a term that is currently used in monasteries to refer about monks, whether choir monks ad/or lay brothers.

I know of many Benedictine monasteries that still employ this term.